# th and td width not working

Tags: html, css

I'm putting together a table where I want the first element of the row if the text is too long should be shortened. For that I use

```
#name{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have this table and just want "me" you can use the abbreviation text should be very long

```css
#name{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="name" style="width:20%">Test name test name test name</th>
      <th id="number">547821365</th>
      <th id="address">test #10900</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

But this does not work, always the first element is enlarged depending on the text and interrupts my other columns.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're after? Also, you're missing a closing quote in `<table style="width:100%>`

Comment: What I look for is that the first column is small so the text is inside can be shortened but I can not @j08691

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/sdbj758n/?

Comment: Yes, that exactly. But I have a problem giving fixed to the table. I am using jquery mobile and have hidden two columns. It deforms to display them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add float:left to your name css class. Here is my fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/rahulpandey034/oxxnpuo2/

```css
#name{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="name" style="width:20%">Test name test name test name</th>
      <th id="number">547821365</th>
      <th id="address">test #10900</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: @Nico Hernandez Torres what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: he first column is not  smaller